# Separate photos of Photo

Tags: c#, winforms

See the following Photo :

[image]

How can I programmatically separate the three photos?

Comment: @SLaks, I think he want's to know how to take an image of images(as shown) and break it up into three different image files.

Comment: This question is too vague and to wide for anyone to know what a useful answer would be. You should clarify what you are trying to do, or I fear that this will be closed pretty soon.

Comment: +1 Overly brief, but seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to figure out how to read and write graphics files, but once you know that, you just have to look for the continuous white space between the images.  The color of all those pixels is identical.

Alternatively, you could apply an [edge detection algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection)